# Cannot set password for 'root'@'localhost' in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, security, passwords, password-protection

I tried to set password for `root` with `mysqladmin` like this:

```bash
sunqingyao@sunqingyao-MacBookAir:~$ sudo mysqld_safe --user=mysql &
[1] 8538
sunqingyao@sunqingyao-MacBookAir:~$ mysqladmin -u root password
New password: 
Confirm new password: 
Warning: Since password will be sent to server in plain text, use ssl connection to ensure password safety.
```

However, I can still log in as `root` without a password:

```
sunqingyao@sunqingyao-MacBookAir:~$ mysql -u root
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 17
Server version: 5.7.18 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> SELECT User, Host, HEX(authentication_string) FROM mysql.user;
+-----------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| User      | Host      | HEX(authentication_string)                                                         |
+-----------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| root      | localhost | 2A36333834303341353032304237313045463146464537413041463546443635453244324430453637 |
| mysql.sys | localhost | 2A5448495349534E4F544156414C494450415353574F52445448415443414E42455553454448455245 |
+-----------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

As you can see, I don't have to use `mysql -u root -p` to select something from a database.

However, if I run `mysql -u root -p` and enter a wrong password, I won't be able to log in.

```bash
sunqingyao@sunqingyao-MacBookAir:~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Here is the output of `strace mysql -u root`:

```bash
sunqingyao@sunqingyao-MacBookAir:~$ sudo mysqld_safe --user=mysql &
[1] 4404
sunqingyao@sunqingyao-MacBookAir:~$ strace mysql -u root
execve("/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql", ["mysql", "-u", "root"], [/* 72 vars */]) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x1cf2000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f65649fa000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=113913, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 113913, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f65649de000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260`\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=138696, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2212904, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f65645ba000
mprotect(0x7f65645d2000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f65647d1000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x17000) = 0x7f65647d1000
mmap(0x7f65647d3000, 13352, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f65647d3000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0!\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=31712, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2128832, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f65643b2000
mprotect(0x7f65643b9000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f65645b8000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x7f65645b8000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\240\r\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=14608, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f65649dd000
mmap(NULL, 2109680, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f65641ae000
mprotect(0x7f65641b1000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f65643b0000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7f65643b0000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0`^\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=138112, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2233544, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f6563f8c000
mprotect(0x7f6563fad000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f65641ac000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x20000) = 0x7f65641ac000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0 \235\10\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1566440, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3675136, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f6563c0a000
mprotect(0x7f6563d7c000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f6563f7c000, 49152, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x172000) = 0x7f6563f7c000
mmap(0x7f6563f88000, 13312, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f6563f88000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0V\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1088952, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f65649dc000
mmap(NULL, 3178744, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f6563901000
mprotect(0x7f6563a09000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f6563c08000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x107000) = 0x7f6563c08000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0p*\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=89696, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2185488, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f65636eb000
mprotect(0x7f6563701000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f6563900000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x15000) = 0x7f6563900000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P\t\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1868984, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3971488, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f6563321000
mprotect(0x7f65634e1000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f65636e1000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1c0000) = 0x7f65636e1000
mmap(0x7f65636e7000, 14752, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f65636e7000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0p\310\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=167240, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f65649db000
mmap(NULL, 2264256, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f65630f8000
mprotect(0x7f656311d000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f656331c000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x24000) = 0x7f656331c000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f65649da000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f65649d9000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f65649d7000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f65649d7740) = 0
mprotect(0x7f65636e1000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f656331c000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f6563c08000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f65649d6000
mprotect(0x7f6563f7c000, 40960, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f65643b0000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f65641ac000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f65647d1000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f65645b8000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f65649fc000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f65649de000, 113913)          = 0
set_tid_address(0x7f65649d7a10)         = 4411
set_robust_list(0x7f65649d7a20, 24)     = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {0x7f65645bfb50, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f65645cb390}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {0x7f65645bfbe0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f65645cb390}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x1cf2000
brk(0x1d24000)                          = 0x1d24000
ioctl(0, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
dup(1)                                  = 3
close(3)                                = 0
stat("/etc/my.cnf", 0x7ffc05533210)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/etc/mysql/my.cnf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1190, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/mysql/my.cnf", O_RDONLY)     = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1190, ...}) = 0
read(3, "# Copyright (c) 2015, 2016, Orac"..., 4096) = 1190
open("/etc/mysql/conf.d/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
getdents(4, /* 4 entries */, 32768)     = 120
getdents(4, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(4)                                = 0
stat("/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=875, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf", O_RDONLY) = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=875, ...}) = 0
read(4, "# Copyright (c) 2015, 2016, Orac"..., 4096) = 875
read(4, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
stat("/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqldump.cnf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=55, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqldump.cnf", O_RDONLY) = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=55, ...}) = 0
read(4, "[mysqldump]\nquick\nquote-names\nma"..., 4096) = 55
read(4, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
stat("/usr/local/mysql/etc/my.cnf", 0x7ffc05533210) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/sunqingyao/.my.cnf", 0x7ffc05533210) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/sunqingyao/.mylogin.cnf", 0x7ffc05533210) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
socket(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(3)                                = 0
socket(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(3)                                = 0
open("/etc/nsswitch.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=529, ...}) = 0
read(3, "# /etc/nsswitch.conf\n#\n# Example"..., 4096) = 529
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=113913, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 113913, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f65649de000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffc05537460) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls", 0x7ffc05537460) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64", 0x7ffc05537460) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=16384, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffc05537460) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls", 0x7ffc05537460) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64", 0x7ffc05537460) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=69632, ...}) = 0
open("/lib/tls/x86_64/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffc05537460) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/tls", 0x7ffc05537460)        = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/x86_64", 0x7ffc05537460)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib/tls/x86_64/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffc05537460) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/tls/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/tls", 0x7ffc05537460)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64", 0x7ffc05537460) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
munmap(0x7f65649de000, 113913)          = 0
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=113913, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 113913, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f65649de000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260!\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=47600, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2168600, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f6562ee6000
mprotect(0x7f6562ef1000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f65630f0000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xa000) = 0x7f65630f0000
mmap(0x7f65630f2000, 22296, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f65630f2000
close(3)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7f65630f0000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f65649de000, 113913)          = 0
open("/etc/services", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=19605, ...}) = 0
read(3, "# Network services, Internet sty"..., 4096) = 4096
read(3, "\t\t# IPX\nipx\t\t213/udp\nimap3\t\t220/"..., 4096) = 4096
read(3, "nessus\t\t1241/tcp\t\t\t# Nessus vuln"..., 4096) = 4096
close(3)                                = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {SIG_IGN, [PIPE], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f65633564b0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4763056, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4763056, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f6562a5b000
close(3)                                = 0
stat("/usr/local/mysql/share/charsets/Index.xml", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=18710, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/local/mysql/share/charsets/Index.xml", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "<?xml version='1.0' encoding=\"ut"..., 18710) = 18710
close(3)                                = 0
futex(0xa4bfe0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(3306), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, [1], 4) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, [1], 4) = 0
recvfrom(3, "J\0\0\0\n5.7.18\0\20\0\0\0[\\F\16Y7\177^\0\377\377\10\2\0\377\301"..., 16384, 0, NULL, NULL) = 78
sendto(3, " \0\0\1\205\256\377\1\0\0\0\1!\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 36, 0, NULL, 0) = 36
open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY)          = 4
read(4, "\315Mo\221\253\t\220\277\v\310\376\331g9\314\250\276X\226\205\336A\253\260>z\241\325\333m\244\353", 32) = 32
open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY)          = 5
read(5, "\332\337E\20\377\202\237-X\237\317\313\323\264\35LK\344k\365\t\351\244\267\33:6\247\304\30\300\\", 32) = 32
futex(0xa4c910, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
sendto(3, "\26\3\2\0K\1\0\0G\3\2\254y\243\"\274\202(\243\353Zf\271\364\f\365\6\30\356\23\365-"..., 80, 0, NULL, 0) = 80
ioctl(3, FIONREAD, [0])                 = 0
recvfrom(3, "\26\3\2\0J\2\0\0F\3\2\242\304\350\3671\247\271\260\274b\257\357\4\1)\266\305)\3130|"..., 64, 0, NULL, NULL) = 64
ioctl(3, FIONREAD, [1595])              = 0
recvfrom(3, "\363\275k\205\223\n\177\26\nm\300\272\0009\0\26\3\2\2\376\v\0\2\372\0\2\367\0\2\3640\202"..., 1595, 0, NULL, NULL) = 1595
open("/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 6
fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=414, ...}) = 0
fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=414, ...}) = 0
read(6, "TZif2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 414
lseek(6, -249, SEEK_CUR)                = 165
read(6, "TZif2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 249
close(6)                                = 0
sendto(3, "\26\3\2\0\7\v\0\0\3\0\0\0\26\3\2\1\6\20\0\1\2\1\0'\307\2404R\342\225n\30"..., 354, 0, NULL, 0) = 354
ioctl(3, FIONREAD, [75])                = 0
recvfrom(3, "\24\3\2\0\1\1\26\3\2\0@\16@\321&u\307Gn\202\363\305Y\225l\2670\374'\207G\213"..., 75, 0, NULL, NULL) = 75
sendto(3, "\27\3\2\0\360\320\317\210+\317\n\374\6\270\2438m\2;.\244n\364V\322/=\260\225\202J#"..., 245, 0, NULL, 0) = 245
ioctl(3, FIONREAD, [0])                 = 0
recvfrom(3, "\27\3\2\0@F\333\216\22\311\355b`\212\245\335#\330`-1\320\303\236\317\344\2231\371M\332\374"..., 64, 0, NULL, NULL) = 64
ioctl(3, FIONREAD, [5])                 = 0
recvfrom(3, "0\35\216\351\223", 5, 0, NULL, NULL) = 5
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x410da0, [INT], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f65633564b0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {0x411d90, [QUIT], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f65633564b0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {0x4120c0, [HUP], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f65633564b0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, {0x411940, [WINCH], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f65633564b0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
ioctl(0, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=24, ws_col=80, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 1), ...}) = 0
write(1, "Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  C"..., 58Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
) = 58
sendto(3, "\27\3\2\0P\373\234Q\34\365)\377\375#\372\242f\211\236b<<\"R2m\202\234\203\243E9"..., 85, 0, NULL, 0) = 85
ioctl(3, FIONREAD, [149])               = 0
recvfrom(3, "\27\3\2\0\220~\360Z\0n\345\215\307[l\271dZ\343\237\360\244\330!w>r|!\304\356("..., 149, 0, NULL, NULL) = 149
write(1, "Your MySQL connection id is 16\nS"..., 83Your MySQL connection id is 16
Server version: 5.7.18 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
) = 83
write(1, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
write(1, "Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle"..., 214Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.
) = 214
write(1, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
readlink("/home/sunqingyao/.mysql_history", 0x7ffc05538020, 511) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
ioctl(0, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache", O_RDONLY) = 6
fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=26258, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 26258, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 6, 0) = 0x7f65649f3000
close(6)                                = 0
futex(0x7f65636e68c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [WINCH], [], 8) = 0
ioctl(1, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
stat("/home/sunqingyao/.terminfo", 0x1d0f230) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/etc/terminfo", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/lib/terminfo", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/share/terminfo", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
access("/etc/terminfo/x/xterm-256color", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/lib/terminfo/x/xterm-256color", R_OK) = 0
open("/lib/terminfo/x/xterm-256color", O_RDONLY) = 6
fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3417, ...}) = 0
read(6, "\32\1%\0&\0\17\0\235\1\262\5xterm-256color|xterm"..., 4096) = 3417
read(6, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(6)                                = 0
ioctl(1, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=24, ws_col=80, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
ioctl(0, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=24, ws_col=80, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
ioctl(1, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(0, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(0, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or TCSETSW, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(0, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
brk(0x1d46000)                          = 0x1d46000
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [HUP INT QUIT TERM CONT TSTP WINCH], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
getuid()                                = 1000
geteuid()                               = 1000
getgid()                                = 1000
getegid()                               = 1000
open("/home/sunqingyao/.editrc", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/sunqingyao/.mysql_history", O_RDONLY) = 6
fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=734, ...}) = 0
read(6, "_HiStOrY_V2_\nSELECT\\040User,\\040"..., 4096) = 734
read(6, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(6)                                = 0
write(1, "Type 'help;' or '\\h' for help. T"..., 79Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
) = 79
write(1, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=414, ...}) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [HUP INT QUIT TERM CONT TSTP WINCH], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x4c0820, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f65645cb390}, {0x410da0, [INT], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f65633564b0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {0x4c0820, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f65645cb390}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {0x4c0820, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f65645cb390}, {0x411d90, [QUIT], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f65633564b0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {0x4c0820, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f65645cb390}, {0x4120c0, [HUP], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f65633564b0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {0x4c0820, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f65645cb390}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCONT, {0x4c0820, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f65645cb390}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, {0x4c0820, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f65645cb390}, {0x411940, [WINCH], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f65633564b0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [WINCH], [], 8) = 0
ioctl(0, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=24, ws_col=80, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
write(1, "mysql> ", 7mysql> )                  = 7
ioctl(0, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(0, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or TCSETSW, {B38400 opost isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(0, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
read(0,
```

Comment: What happens if you use `-p` with the *right* password?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot In that case, I'm able to log in. In other words, `mysql -u root -p` with the correct password is identical to `mysql -u root`.

Comment: Did the password somehow get added to `my.cnf` or `.mylogin.cnf`? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-security-user.html  That's what it sounds like.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot No, I never added that manually, and I don't think any program would do this automatically. Actually, I don't even have a `my.cnf` file in my home directory.

Comment: You wouldn't thing that, but I wouldn't think Oracle would do a lot of the things they do to MySQL in the interest of being "helpful."  I would run the `mysql` client with whatever the Mac equivalient of `strace` is -- it traces all system calls so that you can see (among other things) what files are being read.  Another possibility, this is the work of the [auth_socket plugin](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/03/16/change-user-password-in-mysql-5-7-with-plugin-auth_socket/).

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I'm running Ubuntu 16.06 on a MBA, so I can use `strace mysql -u root`. However, the resulting output isn't obvious, so I've post it in my question. Please take a look.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Whoaaa I just discovered that my `my.cnf` file contains the password for root@localhost, and I can't remember when I did this! Thanks for your help. Please write an answer, so that I can upvote and accept it!

Answer (score 1):

Run `mysql_secure_installation` command and enter your mysql root password, if no password just hit `ENTER` to skip and then you can set mysql root password at first step.

Simply press `y` or hit `ENTER` to get default options.

[mysql_secure_installation Documents](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mysql_secure_installation/)

Hope this help :)